# How to optimize the k parameters in dynamic linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I am starting to use R's [dynlm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynlm/index.html) package. Currently I am just looking at the fit and eyeball which choice of lags might be the best. Is there a standard way or a strategy to determine the best k parameters for `L()`. What I often see is ridiculously high lags like k=10 in a quarterly series delivering the best fit. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: how you determine best lags? From my personal practice omitting some *bad periods of time* by lags my produce better fits, but the model is not passing the _laugh test_. So what is the origin of your data? And yes you can do subset searches, a lot of different data mining techniques are available.

Comment: That's exactly my question to more experienced users: Are there better / other determinants than just an improved fit? Obviously I should use a serious model, but still I wonder whether there is some good strategy to follow in order to get a good first guess up to which order lags should be relevant. Data is e.g. quarterly trend deviation from some stock index.

Comment: have you tried any information criteria like AC/BIC/HQ to optimize the lag choices? Another option could be cross-validation like out-of-sample and jack-knife performance.

Comment: thx Dmitrij, just looked briefly into BIC but none of the others. Any good pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You could cross-validate your different models, and then compare some metric of their out-of-sample accuracy.

You can find R code for cross-validating time series [here](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/tscvexample/), [here](http://moderntoolmaking.blogspot.com/2011/11/functional-and-parallel-time-series.html) and [here](http://moderntoolmaking.blogspot.com/2011/11/time-series-cross-validation-2.html).